# Can we add multiple tags to a AWS resource with one aws cli command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to add tags to Ec2 resource using aws cli command with jenkins:-

The command is:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources $instance_id --region $region --tags Key=$Tagkey,Value=$Tagvalue
```

My question here is that can we add more than one key/value to this resource with one aws cli command or we need to run this command multiple times if I want to add more key/value pairs?

Comment: How this question is related to Jenkins? I mean, does this tag `jenkins` is necessary/relevant?

Answer (score 16):

Yes you can add multiple tags using one AWS cli command seperated by space between tags.
For ex:

```
  aws ec2 create-tags --resources $instance_id --region $region  --tags "Key"="owner","Value"="admin" "Key"="environment","Value"="test" "Key"="version","Value"="1.0" .
```

Answer (score 9):

This exact thing works perfectly fine for me.

```bash
aws --region eu-central-1 ec2 create-tags --resource $subnet_id \
--tags Key=Region,Value=eu-central-1 Key=Stage,\
Value=Dev Key=Owner,Value=somevaluehere Key=Name,\
Value=dev-Public-3 Key=Type,Value=  Key=Shared,Value=true
```

There are three things especially to pay attention to :

1. There should be a space between each Key,Value pair. Like

   `Key=foo,Value=something<space_here> Key=boo,Value=somethingelse`
2. If we don't add spaces between each pair last pair of Key,Value will be only applied.
3. You can keep any Value empty too provided we have a Key.

Answer (score 0):

It is also perfectly valid to use the following format:

```
--tags "project=my-project" "another-tag=true"
```

which means `project` is the key and `my-project` is the value. Make sure to have a space between `"`.